# convert date format from May 4 2013 2:28AM to 2013-05-04 02:28:34.000 format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, format

I want to convert date format from `May  4 2013  2:28AM` to `2013-05-04 02:28:34.000`.

Any one help me?

Comment: So you have a `VARCHAR` with a date and you want to convert it to a `DATETIME`, or you have a `VARCHAR` with a date and you want to convert it to another `VARCHAR` with a different format or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CAST` or `CONVERT` function to convert date format.

**Using CAST:**

```
SELECT CAST('May 4 2013 2:28AM' AS DATETIME)
```

**Output:**

```
2013-05-04 02:28:00.000
```

**Using CONVERT:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'May 4 2013 2:28AM')
```

**Output:**

```
2013-05-04 02:28:00.000
```